# Angular form checkbox default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, checkbox

I've been trying to grab hold of the Angular forms applying best practices for form validations, that forced me to use the form name and have all of the models as children of it so that I can bind the formname.$valid and all the other stuff.

However I haven't been able to set predefined values to any of the form sub models as I have no access to them in the controller.

My biggest problem right now is how to check for falsy checkboxes because initially the checkbox is unchecked but there is no value, it only gets populated when clicked to change the value.

Here is my form code

```
  <form name="addAppForm" ng-if="creatingApp == false">

      <input type="text" placeholder="App Name" required autofocus ng-model="addAppForm.appName">

      <input icheck id="ios" type="checkbox" ng-init="addAppForm.iOS = false" ng-model="addAppForm.iOS">
       <label for="ios"><i class="icon-apple"></i> iOS {{addAppForm.iOS}}</label>

       <input icheck id="android" type="checkbox" ng-init="addAppForm.android = false" ng-model="addAppForm.android">
       <label for="android"><i class="icon-android"></i> Android {{addAppForm.android}}</label>

    <button ng-disabled="addAppForm.$invalid && (addAppForm.iOS != true && addAppForm.android != true)" type="submit" ng-click="addNewApp(addAppForm.iOS, addAppForm.android, addAppForm.appName)" class="button front-primary large radius expand">Let's GO!</button>

  </form>
```

The "required" directive doesn't apply to the checkboxes and I've tried initializing the model but with no luck.

Comment: read the angular checkbox docs. What  does `no access in controller` mean?

Comment: when should it be valid?  If the form is valid plus (both checkboxes true) or one of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a named form like that, it is added to your controller's scope. You can access it inside the controller using the name, similar to in the HTML:

```
$scope.addAppForm.android;
```

This should evaluate to true/false any time after the form has been set up, even if it hasn't been clicked yet.

Edit: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0wmxb3u/) where form is accessed in the controller.

Comment: I've actually tried that but didn't work .. throws an error for an unknown variable, and $scope.addAppForm value is always undefined in the controller

Comment: Sounds like there could be some other problem then. Is the form definitely within that controller's scope?

Comment: yeah, but as @charlietfl said there looks like there is no way to access it from the controller.

I've found a work around and posted my solution here, but still can't make any operations on the form model in the controller.

Comment: I think he was asking what you meant - as you should be able to access it.

Comment: Added a fiddle showing what I mean, in case I misunderstood. When you click on 'What is Android', it will show the value of that checkbox from within the controller.

Comment: Cool, that works ... maybe because I was accessing it before any interaction and before I used the ng-init directive.

Thanks for creating the fiddle, I'll mark your answer as the correct solution just update it with the fact that we need to use ng-init to give initial value and thus access it in the controller, so that no one gets lost in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what's wrong with my code, the ng-init actually works, I just mixed up the operators here -->> `ng-disabled="addAppForm.$invalid && (addAppForm.iOS != true && addAppForm.android != true)"`

Should have been `ng-disabled="addAppForm.$invalid || (addAppForm.iOS != true && addAppForm.android != true)"`

Still the problem persists of not being able to access the form from the controller not even in the same view outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why u have to save your data in the Formcontroller u can use a object ( here i call it 'model' ) and put all your form values inside. Your Formcontroller object ( 'addAppForm' ) has functionality and saves validation errors see here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController This object is added to the scope of your Controller late in the initialisation of your Controller

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

```
Directive that instantiates FormController.

If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.
```

Here is the way to have the form invalid if not at least one checkbox is selected

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myController1", function($scope) {

  $scope.model = {
    "ios": false,
    "android": false
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController1">
  <form name="addAppForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="App Name" required autofocus ng-model="model.appName" />
    <input id="ios" name="ios" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.ios" ng-required="!model.ios && !model.android" />
    <label for="ios"><i class="icon-apple"></i> iOS</label>
    <input id="android" name="android" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.android" ng-required="!model.ios && !model.android" />
    <label for="android"><i class="icon-android"></i> Android</label>

    <button ng-disabled="addAppForm.$invalid " type="submit" ng-click="addNewApp(model.ios, model.android, model.appName)" class="button front-primary large radius expand">Let's GO!</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I actually wanted to check that at least one of them is selected and the input isn't empty, but using the angular convention for the form sub models so that I can submit the form object as it is and hopefully use the `required` directive on the checkboxes to affect the formName.$valid status